# Error in Tipler?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, textbook-erratum

I was reading Tipler et al. when I read this statement on p. 387:

[image]

I thought that the gravitation potential energy of a two-particle system should be negative, if $U = 0$ at infinite separation. Do they mean to say $U = -2Gm_1m_2/r$?

Comment: And what’s up with the 2?

Comment: I assume that that is because there are two particles, each experiencing a potential energy of Gm1m2/r

Comment: It doesn’t work that way.

Comment: how would it work then?

Comment: Surely this book somewhere derives the gravitational potential energy of two masses! You should also be able to find PSE questions about this.

Comment: Comments are not the place to explain something that takes several pages in a textbook.

Comment: This is the third mistake you’ve found in Tipler! You are a careful reader, which is admirable, while Tipler and his co-authors are not careful writers. This is a terrible double mistake that they made. Both the sign and the factor of 2 are wrong. And it is a mistake in something extremely basic and important.

Comment: I knew that Tipler wasn't one of the best intro books, but these questions are lowering my opinion of it more and more... I really suggest switching to a good intro book, like Halliday/Resnick/Krane. It'll cover the same material, but actually correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to visit Wikipedia first if you think there is some error regarding the formulas.

For the given case the correct equation is:
$$U(r) = -G\frac {m_1m_2}{r}$$

You can verify this equation [here on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy).